# iBeacon should present an AlertView

Tags: uialertview, ibeacon

I am struggling a little bit with my UIAlertViews I want to display to the user when getting in range of a beacon. I want the UIAlertview only appear, when a certain distance to the beacon has been reached. First I thought about firing the Alertview in the "didrangebeacons" delegate method. But this would fire the AlertView once per second. Then I thought I should do this in the didEnterRegion, but then it will be fired as soon as the user is in range (maybe 20m away).

What would be the best practice to implement that correctly? I thought about a flag I would set. For example: create a flag called "showAlert" and set it initially to "YES" in the DidEnterRegion Delegate Method. As soon as a certain RSSI is reached I Present the alertview and set it to NO after that. As soon as the region of the beacon has been exited I will be set back to YES.

Is this the "correct" way to do that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your didRangeBeacons method I would check the accuracy property of the CLBeacon object and/or the RSSI to determine if the beacon is close enough.

Accuracy is an estimate in meters and may suit you better than using RSSI although I'd imagine both are just as compatible.

I'd then set your flag to the state where the alert has been shown and show the alert. On the delegate method "didExitRegion" I'd reset the flag so that you are ready to get a notification again if you go back into the region.

Answer (score 3):

You only get distance information in the didRangeBeacons method. In that method you will get an array of beacons. You need to decide what to do if there is more than one beacon in the array. What I do is to loop through and find the closest beacon (based on the accuracy reading, which is really approximate distance)

You will get called sometimes with an empty beacons array, or with all of the beacons showing a proximity of unknown and/or an accuracy value of -1. You need to make sure you handle those cases.

Also, things get messed up if you are in the background. In that case when you enter range of a beacon you get a didEnterRegion call, and then a few ranging calls (for about 5 seconds, based on my testing.) After that the ranging calls stop, and you don't get any more unless the user returns your app to the foreground. If you are running in the background and ignore the first few ranging calls because the user isn't close enough, you never get notified when the user DOES get closer.

Comment: Good piece of information! So I need the didRangeBeacons method to get the distance to a beacon I am ranging... but where should I fire the AlertView and how can I handle the case that it only shows up once? As I mentioned: When I would do this in the didRangeBeacons method I would be firing an alert view once per second. Is there any best practice for that? And how would you take care of the background problem? I need to make sure the user gets notified when he is in range of a beacon even if the app is not loaded

Comment: @ISARFAKTOR, you need to map out what you want to happen, and then come up with code logic that implements that. As the other poster said, you probably need a boolean "alertShown" flag. As far as operating from the background, there appear to be some hard limitations. If you're running from the background you can't ignore far-away ranging calls and expect to get called again when the user is closer. It doesn't work.